# Makefile java with package depandancy

Tags: java, jar, makefile

So I'm trying to make a makefile for my raspberry pi (w. raspbian), but it's not working out well with the dependancies

```
JFLAGS = -classpath .:/usr/share/java/'*' -d .
JC = javac
JVM = java

.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $<

.class.jar:
    jar cvf $@ $^

SRC = \
    helloPi.java\
    Commands.java

MAIN = helloPi

default: $(MAIN).jar

CLASSES = $(SRC:.java=.class)

run: $(MAIN).jar
     $(JVM) $(MAIN)

clean:
    rm *.class

helloPi.jar: $(CLASSES)

helloPi.class: Commands.class
Commands.class:
```

when I do **make run** i get the following error:

```
 java helloPi
 Error: Could not find or load main class helloPi
 makefile:22: recipe for target 'run' failed
 make: *** [run] Error 1
```

I tried pretty much everything to get it to run and I'm sure there is nothing wrong with the java files. 
Anyone knows how to fix this, please let me now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is a jar, you should kick it off using `java -jar myJar.jar`

Comment: so it indeed was the -jar, but now I get the next Error: Unable to acces jarfile helloPi

Comment: THen your path must be incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a main method in your jar, your immediate problem seems to be that you're not kicking off the actual jar file.  Try:

```
run: $(MAIN).jar
     $(JVM) -jar $(MAIN).jar
```

instead.

I would probably clean it up a little more by setting MAIN to helloPi.jar so you don't have to keep specifying the .jar part, but that's basically a style issue.

**EDIT**

The dependencies weren't quite right, and you probably want a manifest that tells the jar what class to run.  Something like this should work:

```
JFLAGS = -classpath .:/usr/share/java/'*' -d .
JC = javac
JVM = java -jar
JAR = jar cvfm

SRC = \
    helloPi.java\
    Commands.java

MAINCLASS = helloPi
MAINJAR = $(MAINCLASS).jar

default: $(MAINJAR)

run: $(MAINJAR)
    $(JVM) $(MAINJAR)

clean:
    rm *.class $(MAINJAR) MANIFEST.MF

CLASSES = $(SRC:.java=.class)

$(CLASSES): %.class: %.java
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $<

MANIFEST.MF:
    $(shell echo Main-Class: $(MAINCLASS) > MANIFEST.MF)

$(MAINJAR): $(CLASSES) MANIFEST.MF
    $(JAR) $(MAINJAR) MANIFEST.MF $(CLASSES)

helloPi.class: Commands.class
Commands.class:
```

Comment: so it indeed was the -jar, but now I get the next Error: Unable to acces jarfile helloPi